# regex replace from xml string

Tags: php, regex, xml, dom

Hi i am laoding a 3rd party xml file but its broken it has no root eliment and has no encoding at the start the xml file looks like the demo below

```
    <channel>
    <name>redbull ( amazing red bull plane )</name>
    <url>youtube.com/redbull<url>
    </channel>
    <channel>
    <name>redbull1 ( amazing red bull boat )</name>
    <url>youtube.com/redbull1<url>
    </channel>
```

How do i go about removing the () and all the text within it ?

i dont know regex but have been told this is the best way todo it if i dont want to take apart the html using dom

also how would i go once removed the brackets and text echoing out every name and url like belw

```
    name:url
    name:url
```

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you may try to use such regex

```
/<name>([^\(]+)\s.+<\/name>\s*<url>(.+)<url>/g
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/eN8dL0/1)

There you find explanation of use regex elements

I hope you understand how use this regex in php code

Comment: you are amazing i google regex search and replace and use this and its working perfect thanks you saved me hours of googling